# Word2Vec input and output vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

Going through word2vec tutorial on udacity, and from the paper it seems to be the case that there are seperate matrices for input word vectors and output.

eg. `['the','cat','sat','on','mat']`.
Here the input vectors $w_i$, `'the','cat','on','mat'` will predict the output vector $w_o$ for `'sat'`. It does this via a sampled softmax as shown below where `|context|` is the size of the context words (4 in this case).

[image]

Hence once training is done there could potentially be two vectors for `sat` as a input vector, and another for the output vector. **The question is why not have one matrix**. This will ensure that the input and output vectors for the same words will be aligned.

If it helps, the tensorflow code is attached below **(why not set softmax_weights =  embedding and softmax_biases=0)**:

```
# Variables.
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
softmax_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

# Model.
# Look up embeddings for inputs.
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
# Compute the softmax loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(softmax_weights, softmax_biases, embed,
                               train_labels, num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

### update:

I implemented it without a seperate output matrix and the results still looks good: https://github.com/sachinruk/word2vec_alternate . **I suppose the questions now should be is there a mathematical reason as to why the output matrix should be different.**

Comment: Try to implement it with one matrix and report back your findings.

Comment: See: [In word2vec, for analogies do we use “in” or “out” vectors? - Stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/191375/6552)